# Parse.com iOS queryWithClassName works for some and not others, why?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have several Classes one of which one is User and another one is TestObject.  If I query User (which I learned by trial & error that it should queried as _User) I get the correct record count, but if I query TestObject I get 0.  This happens for some Classes but not for all.  Why is that?

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
             } else {
                 NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.",objects.count);
             }
}];
```

This returns:

> 2012-10-19 13:55:03.239
>   TableViewParseDotCom[5497:10103]
>   Successfully retrieved 24 scores.

But if I change the line, to:

> PFQuery *query = [PFQuery
>   queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];

I get 0 count, but I know I have  45 records.  Why?

Comment: Have you examined the records at Parse using their web-based dashboard? This may help.

Comment: Yes, there is data, things look fine.

Comment: Not sure why you're having a problem with TestObject, but for querying Users, you should use `[PFUser query]` (https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html#//api/name/query)

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for this is you've queried for objects which you don't have access to. Double check that if these objects have an ACL you are logged in as the same user.

Comment: As the owner of the project, I should not need to be logged in as a user, right?  If I want to do statistics on my data-set, I should be able to query these data in general. So, I should be able to see what all my records are.  Then, if I want to see more specific details for a given user, then a query where key matches some value should also work fine.  I will take another look at the ACL suggestion @Thomas

Comment: iOS has no way of knowing that you are the owner of the app. The data browser bypasses all security and reveals all objects. If you are using the REST API, you can use the -X-Parse-Master-Key header instead of the -X-Parse-REST-API-Key header (and, obviously, change the key to the master key) to bypass access restrictions for any analytics you want to generate.

Comment: Roles (https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#roles) is a way to resolve this while still respecting security. Create an "Administrator" role and set the default ACL to allow read access to the Administrator role. Then you can add (and later remove) any users to the role who need this global access.

Answer (score 1):

Along with checking the ACL's for the objects you're querying, you should also take a look at the Settings in the Parse dashboard. If you don't want to force users to log in ensure that "Allow Anonymous Users" is set on On.

Also, in the data browser for the TestObject object, click on the "More" button and then select "Permissions" from the dropdown. Ensure your settings are correct for "Find" and "Get" - set to public with no roles/users to start with to help your debugging. That should ensure that you can query your TestObject objects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the read permissions. These can be programatically set as below:

```
PFACL * defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
[defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

I just ran two queries, one on my users and one on another class (imageClass) and they both returned fine.

User query:

```
// Remember for users we can run a user query instead of needing to specify the class
PFQuery * userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:currentUser.username];

[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * objects, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Other class query:

```
PFQuery * imageQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"bImageClass"];

[imageQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * objects, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Here is a picture of my classes in Parse.

[image: parsemenu]

So I would make sure you have the public access set correctly (in my project this is set just before a query runs) as the code you are using for the queries looks fine.